# How to set theme for jQueryMobile autocomplete search result items

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using text field to search items as auto complete in jquery mobile and its working fine, but the search result showing as without jquery mobile theme. How I can implement the jquery mobile theme for the search result. Here is the image for search result.

[image]

And the HTML for input field as,

```
        <div data-role="content">   
            <input type="text" name="name" id="basic" value="" data-mini="true" placeholder="Select Employee" data-role="listview" data-filter-theme="d" /> 
        </div><
```

Comment: `ul` instead of `input`, http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/autocomplete/

Comment: when using <ul> its not firing the search webmethod